# Trying to draw an image on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I'm trying to draw an image on a JFrame but it does not seem to work. This is the panel where the image is painted:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

public BufferedImage image;

public GraphicsPanel(){

}
  @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
}
```

This is the JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Spelplan extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static BufferedImage image;
public static GraphicsPanel pane;

public Spelplan() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("*IMAGE PATH*"));  
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image not found");
    }

    pane = new GraphicsPanel(); 
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    pane.setVisible(true);

    initComponents();
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    this.add(pane);
    this.pack();
    pane.repaint();        
}
```

When the program runs, the JFrame appears in the correct size but without the image drawn. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You seemingly never loaded any image to draw? You just load it in your `Spelplan` class which does nothing with it other than use its size. You should probably use `g.drawImage(Spelplan.image, [...]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. What errors are you getting ? I don't see that `image` in `GraphicsPanel` ever gets initialized. You may want to change the constructor to `GraphicsPanel(BufferedImage image)`

Comment: @c0der I don't get any errors, however the image is never drawn. The image is initialized in the JFrame and is public.

Comment: @Ben I use the image in the panel to draw it.

Comment: Why you simply don't use a `JLabel` for it?

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos I want to be able to have other labels on top of it.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(("is image null ? ") + (image == null));` print out if added  to `paintComponent` ?

Comment: @c0der I tried it and it does not print anything.

Comment: So it means that  `paintComponent` is never called

Comment: @c0der Thank you for all your help! It worked! However, now that I want to place a button or label on top of this panel, they do not show. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I am sure you don't expect me to know what's seeing the code. Basically you want to add the label to the `JPanel` and use an appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). If you encounter difficulties post a new question (and send me a message here that you have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedImage image` maybe public but `GraphicsPanel` never accesses it.
Anyway, it is better practice to keep `image` private and use a getter to gain access to it, or pass a reference to the constructor:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Spelplan extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static BufferedImage image;
    private String imagePath = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Crystal_Project_bug.png";

    public Spelplan() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imagePath);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Image not found");
        }

        add(new GraphicsPanel(image));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Spelplan();
    }
}

class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public GraphicsPanel(BufferedImage image){
        this.image = image;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Always post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and use photos url's so others can run your code.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! It worked! However, now that I want to place a button or label on top of this panel, they do not show. Do you know how to fix this?